# What do I do with the code Google JS API have given me

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have just configured a Google Map on https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/.

It has given me JSON, and the URL for the Google Static Maps API.

I have generated an API too.

My question is, what do I do with the two things it has given me, and how do I put in on my flat HTML page?

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=-33.9,151.14999999999998&zoom=12&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry%7Ccolor:0xf5f5f5&style=element:labels.icon%7Cvisibility:off&style=element:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x616161&style=element:labels.text.stroke%7Ccolor:0xf5f5f5&style=feature:administrative.land_parcel%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0xbdbdbd&style=feature:poi%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xeeeeee&style=feature:poi%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x757575&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:road%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xffffff&style=feature:road.arterial%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x757575&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xdadada&style=feature:road.highway%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x616161&style=feature:road.local%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&style=feature:transit.line%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xe5e5e5&style=feature:transit.station%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xeeeeee&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Ccolor:0xc9c9c9&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels.text.fill%7Ccolor:0x9e9e9e&size=480x360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just follow these steps:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
,using both the URL and the JSON array given by the wizard

And don't forget to input your API key ;-)

Comment: Thank you buddy :)